# Spring MVC and user defined themes

Tags: spring-mvc, web, themes, velocity, freemarker

I'm working on creating a small Spring MVC app would like to implement some form of theme-ing. I've got experience with using Sitemesh and Tiles but never had any experience in creating a theme-able app before.

I would like to do it in such a way that end users can create there own designs and put them somewhere where the application can load from and use.

I'm not sure what the best mechanism or technologies are for this. I've been thinking of Velocity or Freemarker but have no idea how to approach this solution.

I would like to make the app a war and deploy to Tomcat.

Comment: I think it all depends on what you call a "theme".  Are you allowing them to modify the entire template or just update the colors and images?  If the former I think you would need some means to allow them to write a custom "template" and read it in, if the latter could just get away with injecting CSS on the fly into your pages.  Either way, I think this is a tall order to fill.

Comment: I was thinking of allowing them to redesign the layout as well as change things such as colors.

Comment: I don't know of any out-of-the-box solutions to add theme'ing to Java apps, nor do I believe one exists given the nature of the task. What you are asking is a tall order. I think the best approach would be to provide extension points in both CSS and your template, otherwise your site will be the "wild west".  There is a reason most sites don't offer this functionality, which is why you are finding it hard to find resources on how to do it. I think you are opening up for a huge set of security risks allowing users to submit themes if not done correctly.

Comment: Thanks, I guess i'll have to stick with not allowing user enabled themes.